# props.history.goBack() not working in iOS WeChat browser after first history.push('xxx')

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have tested many times for this behavior and found the bug only in iOS WeChat after first `history.push()`

For example: in the Main page i click a link (using `history.push`) and jump into page A, but the back button (using `props.history.goBack()`) does not work. When I click a link (using `history.push`) in page A, I jump into B page, the back button in page B can go back to page A and now the back button in page A is working fine (meaning that I can go back to the Main page).

No such strange behavior in Android WeChat.

In iOS WeChat, you must jump 2 times to have normal behaviour. Without the second jump operation you cannot go back through the first jump.

Both HashBrowser and BrowserRouter have this bug/error behaviour.

below is my relation package

```
"react": "^16.11.0",
"react-dom": "^16.11.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `history.goBack()` with `history.go(-1)` should provide you with the same functionality and work in both Android and Safari.

Comment: my h5app is limited to run in WeChat  ，not safria browser

Comment: It should still allow you to use `history.go(-1)`

Comment: history.go(-1) does'n work , all jump behavior works fine in android WeChat except the bug above